# What does 'everything, but everything' mean?

Tags: meaning

I am reading an article in this [link](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2020-05-19-what-the-witcher-3-got-right) and can't wrap my head around what this part actually means: "CD Projekt's true genius is that everything, but everything in the game bends towards delivering this uniquely flavoured fantasy to the player. It's intoxicating."

- **Everything, but everything**? What does it mean?

I had a hypothesis that it means that while every part of the game helps with delivering the fantasy, in the very same time, it also makes it far from delivering the fantasy.

Comment: Literally, *nothing*. Idiomatically, *everything*.

Comment: He's emphasising that "everything" leans towards delivery. It's an idiomatic phrase as Lawrence has mentioned above.

Comment: "everything, but everything" is different from "everything but everything".

Comment: Picture a friend describing this wonderful game and telling you that everything, *without exception*, delivers an intoxicating fantasy.

Comment: I only found one relevant hit among the first 50 in a Google search for "everything but everything". As I suspected, the parenthetical echoing emphasiser _but everything_ was set off by a comma at each end. This reinforces my belief that ' ...  everything, but everything, in the game bends towards delivering ...' is standard. Paraphrasing,  ' everything – absolutely everything – in the game bends towards delivering ....'

Comment: *Everything, and I mean everything …*